Retain router transitions with :key while making sure children base views don't refresh
I have an app where I've used :key="$route.path" on the router view for transitions. But the problem is that using :key ends up refreshing the child route base view that ends up calling the certain APIs again.
Routes:
{
  path: "/some-route",
  component: () => import("@/views/SomeView/SomeViewBase.vue"),
  children: [
    {
      path: "view/:entity_id",
      name: "some-entity-details",
      component: () => import("@/views/SomeView/SomeEntityDetails.vue"),
    },
    {
      path: "update/:entity_id",
      name: "some-entity-update",
      component: () => import("@/views/SomeView/SomeEntityUpdate.vue"),
    },
  ]
}

SomeViewBase.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
      // Some content here
    </div>

    <RouterView />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
// Some logic here along with some API calls
</script>

The problem is that switching between the child routes causes the base view to refresh as well. Removing :key from App.vue resolved the problem but I loose the animations.
I expected that using child routes only refreshes the child route view if the route matches ones in the children array.

Have you tried defining the key in SomeViewBase.vue instead of App.vue

@Yitz the point is to make sure the route transitions work. Removing the key from the app.vue router-view will effect the transitions

Does it work to use the transition code seen here in the vue-router documentation, or do you need key to force certain transition changes?

Your request is conflicting.
On one hand, you want Vue to treat each path component as a separate component instance, so each has its own enter and leave animations.
And, at the same time, you want them to be the same component instance, so that API calls made inside mounted or created are only triggered once.
You can't have both: you either use separate route component instances or you don't.
To get both behaviors, I suggest keeping $route.path keys and moving the API calls to a store, or to a higher component in the DOM tree, one which contains the <RouterView />, so that the calls are not re-run when <RouterView /> changes.
If you need more help, you might want to create a runnable minimal reproducible example on codesandbox.io or similar, which could be forked to exemplify the above principle.
The code you shared so far lacks significant details, such as app structure, route transitions, package versions, etc...
